# Adding primary key to PostgreSQL 12 partitioned table without long locking

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I would like to add a primary key to my partitioned table without locking it over a long period of time.

With regular tables I could create an index `CONCURRENTLY` and promote that index to primary key. With partitioned tables, whenever I try to do this, I get the error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  ALTER TABLE / ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX is not supported on partitioned tables
```

The only alternative I see is to not use concurrently and instead call the creation of the Primary Key directly by columns:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
```

However, before I do this locking operation I wanted to ask if someone here knows of another way.

---

[edit] here's the SQL code for what I tried:

```
-- Create an invalid index
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX main_iex ON ONLY table_name (uuid, accessed);

-- Create index on each partition
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY part1_idx ON part1 (uuid, accessed);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY part2_idx ON part2 (uuid, accessed);
...

-- Attach the partition indexes to the invalid one created before
ALTER INDEX main_idx ATTACH PARTITION part1_idx;
ALTER INDEX main_idx ATTACH PARTITION part2_idx;
...

-- At this point my main_idx should be valid

-- Make a primary key using the main index that should be valid after indexing each partition
ALTER TABLE request_log ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX request_log_uuid_accessed_idx;


-- Result is:
-- Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  ALTER TABLE / ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX is not supported on partitioned tables
```

[edit] and here's the SQL code for a working solution, after implementing suggestions from @jjanes. This solution has only minimal duration of the partitioned table being locked:

```
-- For each partition:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY part1_idx ON part1 (uuid, accessed);
ALTER TABLE part1 ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX part1_idx;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY part2_idx ON part2 (uuid, accessed);
ALTER TABLE part2 ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX part2_idx;

...

-- After creating a primary key for each partition, creating a primary key for the partitioned table is very fast
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid, accessed);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should show us what you actually did, rather then leaving us to guess.

It looks like you created a unique index on the master table, then tried to promote it to a primary key.  Instead, create a primary key on each partition individually, and then just create the primary key on the master without specifying an index to use, just specifying the columns.  That creation will just incorporate all of the existing partition primary keys into the new overall primary key, without needing to build any indexes.

Comment: This is already helpful since I don't have to lock the entire table for the duration that the partition creating, but we can lock each partition separately for less time.

What made this work even better is creating an index concurrently on each partition, using that index for making a primary key for that partition (no locking), then creating the primary key on the partitioned table.

Comment: Right.  It seems like kind of a "gotcha" that it doesn't just do the right thing to start with if you should happen to already have an existing unique index on the master.  (But I also don't plan on going in to fix that code myself).  It is also a bit unfortunate that the child tables must have primary keys, just the corresponding unique index is not good enough.